# Execute a php query in an html email before sending it by the mail() function

Tags: php, html, email

I would like to send an item list filled with a php query in a mail... but I don't see how to set my syntaxe for get it working...

```
 <php
    $message = '
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Confirmation de demande de devis | Recapitulatif de la demande</title>
    </head>

    <body>
            <p>Hi '.$gender.' '.name.' blablabla</p>

            <ul>
            '.$req=$bdd->query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id_order = $_POST['id-order']");
            while ($data = $req->fetch())
            {.'
                <li>'.echo $data['item-name'].'</li>
            .'}
            $req->closeCursor();
            .'</ul>
        </body>
    </html>';
?>
```

I alway have a parse error alert, so I guess it's not the right way to do this.
Do you have any idea?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you have "an error" keep in mind that your audience here will not have a working crystal ball - always share all relevant error messages.

Comment: Yeah I understand, but the error message don't display anything really helpfull: 
We've detected syntax errors during parsing.Parse error: parse error on line 129

Comment: Well, if you'd added that, and pointed out which line is #129, the readers here would've had to spend less time finding your problem. The reason that it's not helpful to **you** is the reason you're asking it here, to people for which it **is**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the code out of the variable, like this:

```
$inline = '';
$req=$bdd->query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id_order = $_POST['id-order']");
while ($data = $req->fetch()) {
    $inline .= '<li>'.$data['item-name'].'</li>';
}
$req->closeCursor(); 

$message = '
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Confirmation de demande de devis | Recapitulatif de la demande</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hi '.$gender.' '.name.' blablabla</p>
        <ul>'.$inline.'</ul>
    </body>
</html>';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working, but I change the **$bdd->query** for **$bdd->prepare** to avoid any **' "** errors in the query.

Answer (score 0):

`'foo'. (SOME PHP CODE) .'bar'` doesn't work. You need to seperate what you want to do from your string.

```
$message = '<html><head>etc..';
$req = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id_order = ".intval($_POST['id-order']));
// added intval against sql injections
while ($data = $req->fetch())
{
    $message .= '<li>'.$data['item-name'].'</li>';
}
$message .= 'rest';
```

Comment: The server return a fatal error:

**Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in /homepages/12/d376209303/htdocs/pages/parametres/mail.php on line 123.** The line 123 is the one whit the while ($data = $req->fetch())